# php xml simple problem

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have this php code from a wordpress theme

```
<?php 

....

$image_source = bloginfo('template_url').'/timthumb.php?src='.$slider_images[$i].'&w=940&h=400&zc=1';
echo "<Image Source='".$image_source."'></Image>";

....
?>
```

and the expected result is :

```
<Image Source='http://...timthumb.php?... .png'></Image>
```

instead of that i get this :

```
http://... <Image Source='/timthumb.php?.... .png'></Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bloginfo function prints it's results directly. See [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo).

What happens is that when you set `$image_source` then the bloginfo prints `http://...` and then returns void. The void value is concatenated with the image url that is `'' . '/timthumb..`. Finally you print the text `<image source...>`.

You should use [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead

Comment: Use get_bloginfo instead. There was link in the reference to this function.